# Run jQuery on Specific URL

Tags: jquery, url, animation

I have a little jQuery snow animation that I want to only run on the index page. Is there a way to edit the jQuery to make it run just on the home page? I've tried the if statement below but it doesn't seam to work, the animation stops completely. This is on a Joomla site so maybe the url could be wrong, I dont know a whole ton about the Joomla file system.

```
<script>
    if (top.location.pathname === 'index.php'){
         jQuery(document).ready( function(){
              jQuery.fn.snow({ minSize: 5, maxSize: 30, newOn: 500, flakeColor: '#FFFFFF' });
        });
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: What is `top` defined as?

Comment: `console.log(top.location.pathname)` or, better yet, just type `top.location.pathname` into your javascript console directly on your home page, then another page to get an idea of what you should be looking for.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! When I typed that command in it returned a "/" so I replaced the "index.php" in my code with the / and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you.

```
$(function() {
 var url = document.location.href;
 if (url.indexOf("index") > -1) {
     // Your Code here
}

});
```

Comment: Tried your code but it stops the animation, thanks for the solution though.

Comment: Show a fiddle of how you used it. you must have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the animation script to index.php (after removing the if condition) instead of your site-wide script file.

Comment: Good option to consider.

Comment: Sadly with Joomla the index.php is defined as the main template.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your host name is `domain.com` and your `index.php` is in the root web folder. This means that each of the following valid URLs to trigger the animation:

1. http://domain.com
2. http://domain.com/
3. http://domain.com/index.php

You would need the following code to accomplish your goal:

```
var url = window.location.href,
    uP = url.indexOf('/') > -1 ? url.split('/') : [];

if( uP.length == 3 || (uP.length > 3 && (uP[3] == '' || uP[3].indexOf('index.php') == 0)) ){
     jQuery(document).ready( function(){
          jQuery.fn.snow({ minSize: 5, maxSize: 30, newOn: 500, flakeColor: '#FFFFFF' });
    });
}
```